# Pass JSON file to Javascript ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is currently : How to pass a JSON Object (As it is or as a C# object deserialized with Newtonsoft.Json) to a javascript file.

I tried the following method :

```
Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='data' type='hidden' value='", json_file, "' />"));
```

but when the json file is rendered in HTML (as a html attribute) it stops on the quote character, i tried to escape it but it's not working either.
So when in my javascript file i use JSON.parse() the syntax is not valid.

Problem Solved :
- Declared a javascript variable Data in my .cshtml file, put the jsonfile as a @ViewBag element inside.
- got it in my javascript by window.Data
- parsing it as json, using it, magic done.

(Thanks for those who answered)

Comment: is the json_file the json string or the name of the file?

Comment: it's a string. (i opened a StreamReader and read it to the end and store it in a string). The json file is well formated i got my app to work with json files without quote characters.

Comment: do you have any `'` or `>` in the `json_file`?

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem i'm describing. When i got json file with quotes it crashes when the json file is quotes free it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a `json` object, why not insert the object in a javascript variable on the page, as presumably you want to use the variable e.g. in Ajax?

```
function someThingClicked(){
  var myObject = <%= json_file %>;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomeUrl",
    data: myObject,
    success: function () { },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"});
}
```

This should serve something like the below to the browser:

```
var myObject = {
  someField : 'someValue'
};
...
```

If you are using razor, you would write it out something like:

```
  var myObject = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.json_file);
```

Assuming that you've added the `json_file` string into `ViewBag` from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you can try use [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it's a result of you concatenation results in termination of the `value`sttribute value before you intended. E.g. you have a `'`character in the `json_file`

as an example if the file contains

```
var x = 'this is a string'
```

then the result of your concatenation would yield invalid html

```
<input id='data' type='hidden' value='var x = 'this is a string'' />
```

notice that the `value` attribute is terminated after `var x =` and that the final "attribute" `string` is missing an `=` prior to the value (the empty string `''`)

to avoid that you should assign the json to a variable and then assign that value as the value to the input element

```
Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='data' type='hidden'/>",
                             "<script>$(function(){var x = ", json_file,
                             ";$("#data").val(JSON.stringify(x));</script>");
```

(assuming you are already using jQuery otherwise you'd have to do it with plain vanilla JS which is a little more work but can be done

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='data' type='hidden' value=\"", json_file.Replace('\"', '\''), "\" />"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### An other solution instead of printing json string inside the html attribute

1. Create an action that returns your json in your controller

   ```
   public string GetData()
   {
       //read your json file
       return json_file; //return your json string
   }
   ```
2. On View side, put your input tag and fetch json_file through an ajax request

   ```
   <input id='data' type='hidden' />
   <script>
       $(function () {
           $.post("/yourControllerName/getData", {}, function (response) {
               $("#data").val(response);
           },'json');
       });
   </script>
   ```